# How I set the signature area in a custom way

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the API to set the signature area. Right now with the acnhorString I can set the area based on this text. Up to here everything ok.

[image]

But I need to do this with existing PDF document and have no opportunity to edit or put place holder text/pdf field. Thus how can we dynamically position the tab (signature field) at desired position.

I was following this documentation ->

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this instead:

```
documentId : "1",
pageNumber : "1",
xPosition : "100",
yPosition : "100"
```

You can place it by picking the document, page and exact pixel position.